# How to add a http software site to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, http, https

Can anyone tell me how to force eclipse to use the software site i actually added? and not try to use https as the error in the picture below shows.

[image]

Comment: If this is Eclipse 4.28 see https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.28/platform.php#force-https

Answer (score 2):

In the **preferences *Install/Update > Trust***, in the tab ***Authorities***, set the *protocol rule* for ***http*** from *Redirect (Default)* to ***Allow***.

Please note, HTTP should be used for security reasons only for internal update sites.

See also:

- [Eclipse 4.28 - New and Noteworthy - CVE-2021-41033: Enforce https protocol](https://CVE-2021-41033:%20Enforce%20https%20protocol)
- [My video *Eclipse 2023-06 Java IDE Improvements* showing this starting at 7:42](https://youtu.be/OQe_hafeuz8?t=462)