# Eclipse is using https instead of http

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install a plugin located at a location(url is of organization) which is "http://some-url/eclipse-update-site/"(ending with slash)
While trying to use "Install new software" for installing the same,
I am getting error - Unable to read repositry at "https://some-url/eclipse-update-site/site.xml"

url is getting changed from http to https resulting in the issue because "http://some-url/eclipse-update-site/" is invalid as https is not supported(checked that by hitting the url explicitly on the browser)

This plugin is specific to eclipse and cannot be installed on any other IDE

I have already tried using Network preference both as native and direct

Can someone suggest what should be done here?

Current Eclipse version - 4.30.0(Although I have already tried installing the plugin on 3.2.0 version as well but getting same error)

I tried installing a plugin but getting could not find repository error because url is changing from http to https. Expectation is that I can install the plugin on the specified url by accessing http on eclipse.

Comment: Does the following answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76711293/6505250